# 404 error being generated on controller actions that use [HttpGet] when clicking on a hyperlink?

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

**Background**

I have an ASP.Net Core v2.0 web application that has the [HttpGet] attribute above action results that don't need to accept a post.

I created a spreadsheet with a list of pages on the website to my marketing team, along with a column of hyperlinks that link directly to each page on the website.

Example Spreadsheet:
[image: Example Spreadsheet]

**Issue**

Once the marketing team started clicking on the links in the spreadsheet, I started to receive 404 errors via email (configured using NLog) although the page did still load for the user.

**Troubleshooting**

I troubleshooted this and uncovered that the issue was down to the [HttpGet] attribute. If I take the [HttpGet] attribute out, clicking on the links in the spreadsheet doesn't generate a 404 error.

The site doesn't generate 404 errors when loading the page (s) via the browser.

I installed fiddler and it looks as though Excel is using the "CONNECT" method.

Fiddler screenshot:
[image: Fiddler screenshot]

I thought this could be the issue as it's not a GET but when I access a page within Chrome, it also shows using the "CONNECT" method in fiddler.

I'm looking to see if anyone else has had this issue and if they got around it? Do I need to add another attribute alongside [HTTPGet] to stop Excel or other 3rd party software causing a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my own issue.

For anyone else that has this issue the fix is to put [HttpGet, HttpHead] as the attribute. If you have a custom route then add another attribute underneath:

[Route("[controller]/custom-action")].

For info, I got to the bottom of this by using the logs from the drop down ASP.Net Core Web Server in the output window in Visual Studio. I could see that when the link was first being requested by Excel, it was using the HEAD method rather than the GET which is why a 404 error was being fired.

Hope that helps someone down the line.